# How does Apache mod_proxy_ajp work when Jboss runs as a cluster with AJP on 2 different ports?

Tags: apache-2.2, cluster, jboss, mod-proxy-ajp

I am trying to get an Apache webserver to load balance to a JBoss cluster, but unfortunately, I dont understand how mod_proxy_ajp works through the load balanced scenerio, since each of the 2 instances of JBoss run AJP on a different port. Since I specify my ProxyPass rule using only one of the ports, what ends up happening is that all the traffic goes through only one of the instances (that I specified using my ProxyPass rule).

```
<Location /jconsole>  
    # somehow I need this to also load balance to port AJP localhost:8209
    ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8109/jconsole
    ProxyPassReverse ajp://localhost:8109/jconsole
</Location>
```

Any help I could get would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you need to configure a balancer.

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
  BalancerMember ajp://localhost:8109/jconsole
  BalancerMember ajp://localhost:8110/jconsole
</Proxy> 

<Location /jconsole>  
  ProxyPass balancer://mycluster/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid nofailover=On
</Location>
```

More options can be found at the apache documentation at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass.

Comment: Thanks very much.  You might want to edit your answer though:  the Proxy directive cannot be inside the Location directive.

Comment: Change done as requested.